# Google maps direction api with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, maps

I am working on a small website that uses ajax and the google maps API to load directions. I have a DB that stores lat-longs of a few locations and when one is selected from a dropdown an async call is made to the server and a JSON array is returned. I am calling my showPosition function everytime a async call is made.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    console.log(myObj[0].lat);
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                    showPosition(myObj);
                }
            };
```

showPosition is supposed to display the map with the directions.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var mapholder = document.getElementById("mapholder");



    function showPosition(myObj) {
        //Getting all the coorindates
        console.log(myObj);
        fromDirectionLat = myObj[0].lat;
        fromDirectionLong = myObj[0].long;
        toDirectionLat = myObj[1].lat;
        toDirectionLong = myObj[1].long;

        //Setting mapholder style
        mapholder.style.height = '600px';
        mapholder.style.width = '600px';
        mapholder.style.border = 'medium solid #555555';
        var myOptions = {
            center: latlong,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            }
        };


        var directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapholder'), myOptions);
        directionDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
            displayRoute(directionService, directionDisplay);
        }

        function displayRoute(directionService, directionDisplay) {
            var originF = new google.maps.LatLng(fromDirectionLat, fromDirectionLong);
            var destinationT = new google.maps.LatLng(toDirectionLat, toDirectionLong);
            direcionsService.route({
                origin: originF,
                destination: destinationT,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            },
                function (response, status) {
                if(status == 'OK')
                    directionDisplay.setDirections(response);
                else
                    window.alert("failed");
            }) ;

        }


    }
</script>
```

In my console I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: latlong is not defined Ajax:93:17
    showPosition http://localhost:8888/Ajax/:93
    onreadystatechange http://localhost:8888/Ajax/:37
```

I am quite puzzled as to what exactly is happening. I quite new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a variable that is not defined anywhere

```
center: latlong
```

`latlong` does not exist anywhere else in your function. You should define it to the center of the map you want to display

```
var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(your_center_lat, your_center_long)
```

or

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(your_center_lat, your_center_long)
```

Defining the center is up to you :)